# Google map not being displayed

Tags: php, javascript, html

This morning i was trying to implement Google map, but when i load my page than nothing is being displayed. The code is listed below.

```
<?php

?>

<!--===========================HTML==========================-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #map_canvas {
        width: 500px;
        height: 400px;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
      function initialize() {
        var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
        var map_options = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options)
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, ‘load’, initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please let me know what wrong with this code

Comment: Most probable cause is from copying/pasting code from exterior sources. It happens to all of us, eventually ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This was a tricky one, but I've got it: **it's your quotes.** The JavaScript error is `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` on line 24.

Your quotes around the string `load` are part of a character set that JavaScript doesn't recognize. So:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, ‘load’, initialize);
```

Should be changed to:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I've tested your code with that one replacement and it works as desired.

Comment: I'm going to +1 here also, *I have my reasons.*

Comment: I did beat you by 47 seconds :P

Comment: It's not a race for me, but "More Power to You" (*wink*) it's all about finding a "solution", remember that. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

**To further add** to [**Amal Murali's answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18029322/1415724), it's the **irregular single quotes** `‘ ’` in the following line:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, ‘load’, initialize);
```

It needs to be changed to:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

while using: `<body onload="initialize();">` (as per Amal Murali's suggestion)

**Most probable cause**:

- Errors as such come from copying/pasting code from the Internet, *it can happen*.

**How to prevent this:**

- It's always best to double-check code taken from exterior sources.

**Full fixed code:** (it's safe to now copy/paste)

```
<?php

?>

<!--===========================HTML==========================-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #map_canvas {
        width: 500px;
        height: 400px;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
      function initialize() {
        var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
        var map_options = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options)
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize();">
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
function initialize() {
        latlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463);
        options = { zoom: 8, center: latlng1, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), options);
    }
```

And in your code there is an syntax that you need to change like

```
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

And also @Amal said it will work only when it calls on load for the page like

```
<body onload="initialize();">
```

Comment: I like the way you re-coded the function, however you haven't made reference to how it will work. If `<body onload="initialize();">` is not used in conjunction with the OP's code and leaves `<body>` intact, then it won't work. I say this because I tested your code (FF v22) and it didn't work unless `<body onload="initialize();">` (`onload="initialize();"`) was added.

Comment: Yah I know that....but already @Amal had told about that before I edit it...So I kept calm

Comment: I understand. I just thought I would make a note of it, in case the OP did not know what to do with it. We have no idea as to what degree of experience the OP has. Cheers